# Java: Will an unreachable object which points to reachable object be garbage collected?

Tags: java, object, memory-leaks, reference, garbage-collection

Suppose we have a situation like this:

Object A is unreachable, but it has a reference which points to a valid, reachable object. So will object A be garbage collected? Or we are at risk of memory leak?

**EDIT1**

Specifically, I wrote a class tri-nary tree, which has:

```
class Node {
   Node left, mid, right;
   int data;

...
}
```

I implemented delete(Node p) function, which makes p unreachable by set its parent reference to null. However, the other node in the tree (called m), will call this one before deleting p:

```
m.mid = p.mid;  
delete(p);    // Make p unreachable
```

I just want to make sure that that p will be garbage collected, but m still keeps a reference to p.mid

Comment: If the object is not reachable, it can be garbage collected. Full stop.

Comment: Why would you think there's a memory leak here? Harvesting unreachable objects is the GC's job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Object A is unreachable, but it has a reference which points to a valid, reachable object. So will object A be garbage collected?

Yes.  (Eventually).  An unreachable object is a candidate for garbage collection.

> Or we are at risk of memory leak?

No.

When an object is unreachable, any references that it holds are:

- irrelevant to the computation,
- irrelevant to its own reachability, and
- irrelevant to the reachability of the objects that those references refer to.

Now, it may take a long time (i.e. multiple GC runs) before your Object A is *actually* garbage collected.  And until it is actually garbage collected, the closure of objects that it refers too won't be collected either.  However, this is not a memory leak.  If the JVM needs the memory, you can be assured<sup>1</sup> that all unreachable objects are collected before the JVM throws an OOME.

---

<sup>1 - ... modulo certain JVM GC option settings ...</sup>